# eJabberd Service Discovery not show Service Administration (XEP-0133 Commands)

Tags: ejabberd

I tried to use Service Discovery to find out what commands are supported by the xmpp-server as per XEP-0133 (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#disco). The first request for general support tells me that Service Administration is supported. But when I try to get the supported commands I only get the configuration-command. The following image shows the response from the server.

**Reply stanza from server**

[image: Reply stanza from server]

My ejabberd.yml has both `mod_adhoc` and `mod_announce` activated and the admin-account should be able to use the commands.

```
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce

announce:
    - allow: admin

  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
```

What else do I need to configure so that I get more disco#items for setting the Message of the Day etc.?

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd implemented a way to send announcements to users a long time before XEP-0133 was designed, and you can still use that way to send them: an admin sends a stanza to a specific JID, and ejabberd delivers it. That feature doesn't require XEP-0133. See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-announce

How to configure the announcement feature:

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - user1@localhost

access_rules:
  announce:
    allow: admin

modules:
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
```

Some years later, XEP-0133 was designed, and it got implemented into ejabberd. How to configure the XEP-0133 feature:

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - user1@localhost

access_rules:
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_configure: {}
```